# meta.SE question - "Can we find a way make sure that new users acknowledge the on-topic page before being able to post?"

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've noticed a lot of new users come in and ask reasonable-but-actually-off-topic questions.... and asked:

[Can we find a way make sure that new users acknowledge the on-topic page before being able to post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290485/can-we-find-a-way-make-sure-that-new-users-acknowledge-the-on-topic-page-before/290486)

> Over on Music.SE, when a new user asks a question, there is a 'How to
>   Ask' sidebar that says
>
> > **Is your question about music practice, performance, composition, technique, theory, or history?**
> >
> > We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.
> >
> > Provide details. Share your research.
> >
> > If your question is about this website, ask it on meta instead.
>
> The problem is that we get lots of new users asking perfectly sensible
>   questions that are within the scope mentioned above, but fall foul of
>   particular off-topic rules we have there that are outlined on
>   https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.
>
> This leads to the following happening:
>
> - new user wastes time posting off-topic question
> - existing users waste time explaining why the question is off-topic
> - possibly, more time is wasted editing the question to get it on-topic
> - ill-feeling sometimes ensues, partly due to the wasted time.
>
> ...and this happens repeatedly, and it's happening more often as the
>   site gains prominence and user base. I can see that in the future it
>   may start to really become a drain on energy that could be spent
>   adding useful content.
>
> Can we find a way make sure that new users acknowledge the on-topic
>   page before being able to post? Something like being directed through
>   it and having to tick an 'I understand!' box.

Would this be a good idea?

Comment: Won't help, who reads the terms and conditions before clicking accept. And even if you do unxerstand the rules, most people will still take a change. Just take for example, if you ask a question, the system identifies possible duplicates according to your question's title, who goes and actually follow those links in order to find a possible answer before posting a new question

Comment: @rock-on That's certaintly a pessimistic viewpoint... When asking questions, I always check those (or at least read the titles to cull any possible dupes). But I do agree that the fact that this issue exists does lend credit to the need for a better solution.